# Best way to use transaction scope

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I'm using a transaction in Entity Framework. But I'm not sure where to put the transaction scope. Should it be at the beginning, before i do some processing for the entity. Or should I put it after the entity processing but before i call save. Because i read that transaction should be as short as possible.

Should I do this

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) 
{ 
    using (var context = new MyDbContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
    { 
        var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating > 5); 

        foreach (var post in query) 
        { 
            post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
        } 

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();                               
    }
}
```

or this (scope at the very end before save/commit)

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
{   
    var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating > 5); 

    foreach (var post in query) 
    { 
          post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
    } 

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) 
    { 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();                         
    }                             
}
```

Comment: Depends on _why_ you are using transaction. By the way, `SaveChanges` already executes inside transaction.

Comment: In your example above there is no need to explicitly handle transactions See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well for answering your question we first have to look to why we use Transaction Scopes to begin with.
e.g.

Let's imagine you want to buy a car, but you already own a car, so you want to trade yours.

```
public bool TradeCar(Car myCar, Car otherCar)
{
    otherCar.Owner = "Me";
    myCar.Owner = "Other Dude";

    return true;
}
```

Now imagine for a second that the application crashed for some reason in the line where `myCar.Owner = "Other Dude"`, now you have 2 cars!

That's wonderfull if you're a thief but we're all good guys we want everything to go as smooth as possible.

So we add a transaction scope!

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    otherCar.Owner = "Me";
    myCar.Owner = "Other Dude";

    return true;

}
```

Now if your code crashes for any reason both of you guarantee that don't lose their car!

So as long as you're not making anything to fancy you can leave transaction scope aside, I usually use it in the begining of the call if I intent to do more then 1 operation with the database.

Comment: I don't think you are answering the question here. The OP is well aware of what a transaction is. He uses it. The question is what is the better way to write the transaction code block.

Comment: Hi, i'm aware what transactionScope is. My question is where should i put the transactionScope. Is it at the beginning, before i do some processing for the entity or after i process the entity and before i call save? because i read that transaction should be as short as possible

Comment: Yes the transaction should be as short as possible, for this example i'd say to use the bottom one, because you're blocking the transaction to query Post, and you don't need that, so you can use the second one.